# Convert string letters to different ones in JS

Tags: javascript, replace, replaceall

I have this simple JS task that i can't figure out, not so simple for me after all.

Create a function 'converter', that converts letters in this way:

```
T -> C
C -> T
A -> D
X -> Y
```

Function accepts String with letters. All non convertable letters should be removed from string.

Example:

```
 - converter('TTCCAAXX') -> 'CCTTDDYY'
 - converter('TTGG') -> 'CC'
```

I tried something like this -

```
function Converter(str) {
let upperStr = str.toUpperCase()
let newStr = upperStr.replaceAll("T", "C").replaceAll("C", "T")
console.log(newStr)
}

Converter("TTCCAAXX")
```

But this is replacing all the characters and overwriting them and I'm not getting the right results.

Comment: The whole point of codewars is for you use your own brain, not someone else solve it for you...if you can't figure out, skip and go to the next task, unless of course your only concern is to rank up and show off..

Comment: I have no idea what are you talking about, I had this task assigned to me as a homework in JS class.

Comment: oh lol ok, apparently your teacher uses codewars for "inspiration"... So people will give you the answers, but to fix your approach, you'll need replace letters on the left to other letters that don't match letters on the right (let's call them "new" letters), next replace all letters on the right to corresponding letters on the left, and finally replace "new" letters from step one to corresponding letters on right. i.e. T > M; C > T; M > C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a sequential `for` loop which is more efficient (only requires one iteration) and solves the overwriting issue.

For better flexibility we can store the character pairs in an object.

```js
const convertKeyValue = {
  'T': 'C',
  'C': 'T',
  'A': 'D',
  'X': 'Y'
}

function Converter(str) {
  let upperStr = str.toUpperCase()
  var newStr = ''
  for(let i = 0; i < upperStr.length; i++){
    const current = upperStr.charAt(i);
    newStr += convertKeyValue[current] ? convertKeyValue[current] : '';
  }
  return newStr;
}

console.log(Converter('TTCCAAXX'));
console.log(Converter('TTGG'));
```

Comment: Wow, that was quick. Thank you kind sir !

Answer (score 0):

Consider adding a boolean/counter to represent the state in addition to new mappings. That way you don't get recurring or cyclical conversions.